# Adding items to a Hash in ruby, why are items being overwritten?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
chartJsObject = [{label: "Label Stuff", datasets: []}]

i = 0

while i < 5 do
  chartJsObject[i][:datasets] << [rand(10), rand(10)] if chartJsObject[i]
  i+=1
end
```

While I expect `datasets` to include five sets of #s, like `[9, 9]`, `[1, 2]` etc, I get:

```
chartJsObject # => [{"label":"Label Stuff","datasets":[[9,9]]}]
```

What am I doing wrong in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chart_js_object` has only one element, at index 0. So each call to `chart_js_object[i]` where `i` is anything other than zero is returning `nil`. This would cause an error, except that the conditional at the end of your operative provision is causing the code to ignore each iteration after the first.

Let's use [Ruby standards](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars) for variable naming. I'll translate to snake_case. Also, `while` loops are pretty rare in Ruby. To perform an operation a specific number of times, you can just use the `#times` method.

So we end up with this:

```
>> 5.times { chart_js_object[0][:datasets] << [rand(10), rand(10)] }
>> chart_js_object
=> [{:label=>"Label Stuff", :datasets=>[[0, 4], [6, 0], [5, 4], [4, 6], [8, 6]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `chartJsObject` array has only one datum, so the array count is `1`, and array index is `chartJsObject[0]`. The loop body runs only once, as the `chartJsObject` array has only one datum in it, and you have given the condition as

```
if chartJsObject[i]
```

That's the reason it gives you the result like that.